# How to get only one column data out of many when using JpaRepository and hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have done the following implementation by extending the JpaRepository  -

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.erecruitment.app.model.NewUser;
import com.erecruitment.app.model.user;

@Repository
public interface InterviewerDetail extends JpaRepository<NewUser, Integer>{

    public String nativeQuery="SELECT first_name FROM new_user WHERE role in ('technical 
    Interviewer','Hr Interviewer');";

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value=nativeQuery,nativeQuery=true)                           
    public List<NewUser> GetRepo(int id);       
}
```

In the native query above,I just want to get first_name column values out of all other column values .But , when I am trrying to do it , it is giving following exception - java.sql.SQLException: Column 'users_id' not found. I am aware that , it is because of selecting just one column not all columns . But , I need to get one column value only . Ho can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a bit dto and adding that only first_name to it?, List<UserNamesDTO> GetRepo...

Comment: I had not tried it .But tried just now and it worked as expected . Thank you for your time , your suggestion solved my problem .